# Windows 2003 zip from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2003, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you zip a file from the command prompt using ONLY Windows' built-in capability to zip files?](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili)

Is there a way to zip a file (or group of files) from the command line using Windows 2003?  I'd prefer to use built-in commands if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to do it from the command line using only built-in commands. But you can use [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) from the command line; the great thing about 7-Zip is that it's free and open-source.

[Here](http://dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)'s a quick tutorial on using the 7-Zip CLI. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: I'm a fan of 7-zip.  Annoying that I need a 3rd party tool to do what Windows can do natively via UI.

Comment: It's strange indeed. But the Windows zip functionality is not great. It's incredibly slow to archive or unarchive something using the built in tools (from what I remember, it's an order of magnitude slower compared to WinRar or 7-Zip).

Comment: How to set "version to extract"? Default is 2.0, But I want to set it to 1.0

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it **can** be done with built-in Windows commands (much to my surprise, I had pretty much concluded the same as Molly7244).

A very tricky (but perfectly workable) method is described in this other question:

[Can you zip a file from the command prompt using ONLY Windows' built-in capability to zip files?](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili)

Answer (score 1):

[**Using zip and unzip on the Windows command line**](http://stahlforce.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip)

And no, you can't use the 'integrated' Windows ZIP functionality from the commandline.