# Dos command to ZIP a file

Tags: command-line, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 2003 zip from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/35145/windows-2003-zip-from-command-line)

Can somebody please, let me know that how we can zip a file in a Command line. Please, let me know.

Comment: Until it is confirmed that he is indeed searching for a cmd, and not DOS, I don't see how this is a duplicate. Btw, to original author: look at pkzip /? and pkunzip /?

Answer (score 5):

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) comes with a command line variant that will (un)compress to/from all the archive formats it supports (7z, zip, gz, rar, and a few others)

Answer (score 3):

Download command line zip utility from [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Unxutils has a standalone command line zip programme as part of it

http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

alternately 7zip has a cli - and it does quite a few formats.

Answer (score 0):

Install the **zip** and **unzip** packages in your Cygwin environment.  I wouldn't install it for just those two packages, but if you have one already, use it.

Answer (score -1):

there is a compress command.

Comment: Compress is different from zip, but it's a good point, in that DOS does have a standard way of compressing files.  Just not a very good or compatible one :)