# Windows in-built compression command without utilizing any external tools

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, zip, archiving

I want a Windows (7 onward) command line compression and archiving command/script, which doesn't require any external tools or utilities, including PowerShell, as I am not much of Windows scripter. It should be totally independent, like Unix/Linux zip/tar commands.

I have searched a lot for this type of a command or script, but I haven't found any yet. Has anyone found something like this?

Comment: You might check out [Makecab](https://ss64.com/nt/makecab.html) to see if it's suffice. Otherwise, there are ways to create a batch file that will use PowerShell without you needing to touch it at all and I've done this many time easily. I'm not sure if you're reluctant to use PowerShell script explicitly but I can easily create a batch script that will do this that will utilize PowerShell and .Net commands to do what you want without you actually having to touch PowerShell or build a PowerShell script as the batch file logic will take care of all that. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @McDonald's ok I would like to see your Powershell script, if it's that easy and one-click to run as you say it is then I may give it a go, please post your script as an answer.

Comment: Entire folders, but a param with file-type flag would be great, priority is folders though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be an expert script writer to utilize **PowerShell** and you do not need to utilize an explicit **PowerShell** script (or its IDE interface) to use **PowerShell** commands—you can utilize **PowerShell** commands and make them part of the batch script logic to execute and use.

I think you are looking for a **Windows** native way to complete the task, and you just want to ensure it is indeed native to **Windows** and will work on from **Windows 7** and above (newer).

---

### Compressing and Archiving

I've created a batch script below that works from **Windows 10** and **Windows 7** and uses logic that works on older versions of **PowerShell** as well as newer versions just in case I used older logic.

> **Drag and Drop**
>
> Just drag the folder you wish to compress to the batch script and
>   it'll be archived as a zip file and it will create the new zip file in
>   that same location but with the **`<foldername you archive>.zip`** so if
>   you drag **`C:\User\User\Desktop\New Folder`** into the script, it will create
>   **`C:\User\User\Desktop\New Folder.zip`**
>
> **Drag folder to script**
>
> [image]
>
> **Created afterwards**
>
> [image]

### The Script

***Note:*** I've left two variables in the script commented out up top so you can use those and set the source folder and the destination file name explicitly if you wish rather than using the drag and drop method.

<sub><sub>[Source link to the PowerShell  logic idea](https://serverfault.com/questions/456095/zipping-only-files-using-powershell/456706#456706)</sub></sub>

```
@ECHO ON

::SET src_folder=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
::SET destfile=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.zip

SET src_folder=%~1
SET destfile=%~FN1.zip

:DynamicPSScriptBuild
SET PSScript=%temp%\%~n0.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")>>"%PSScript%" 
ECHO $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal         >>"%PSScript%" 
ECHO $includebasedir = $true                                                       >>"%PSScript%" 
ECHO [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("%src_folder%", "%destfile%", $compressionLevel, $includebasedir)>>"%PSScript%" 

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"

EXIT
```

---

### Decompressing and Extracting

I've also created a batch script below that works from **Windows 10** and **Windows 7** and uses logic that works on older versions of PowerShell as well as newer versions just in case I used older logic.

> **Drag and Drop**
>
> Just drag the zip file want to decompress into the script and it will
>   extract the contents of the file to the same folder as the zip file
>   you dragged into the script resides. So if you have
>   **`C:\User\User\Desktop\ZipMe.zip`** and it contains a folder named **`ZipMe`**, once you drag and drop it into the script, it will extract the folder **`ZipMe`** to **`C:\User\User\Desktop`**.
>
> **Drag the zip file to the script**
>
> [image]
>
> **Extracted afterwards**
>
> [image]

### The Script

**Important:** The variable in the **Compressing and Archiving** script ***above (the first script up top)*** shown as `$includebasedir = $true` tells it to zip the actual folder and the contents within. If this value was set to `$false` instead or if you extract from a zip that does not contain the folder, the below script will extract all the files and other contents to the same folder the zip file resides—so 100 files and folders will be extracted if that's what the zip file contained with no containing parent folder within the file.

***Note:*** I've left two variables in the script commented out up top so you can use those and set the destination folder and the zip file name explicitly if you wish rather than using the drag and drop method.

```
@ECHO ON

::SET dest_folder=C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder
::SET zip_file=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test\test.zip

SET dest_folder=%~DP1
SET zip_file=%~1

:DynamicPSScriptBuild
SET PSScript=%temp%\%~n0.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.Filesystem")>>"%PSScript%" 
ECHO [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory("%zip_file%", "%dest_folder%")   >>"%PSScript%" 

:PowerShell
SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"

GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [CreateFromDirectory Method (String, String, CompressionLevel, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ExtractToDirectory Method (String, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

At least Windows 7 (and XP... I'm not quite as sure about the state with Windows 10 yet) doesn't have a command line interface to work with the ZIP compression support provided by "Microsoft Compressed Folders" support (like what Explorer can use).

However, you can do this by simply creating a script file, and then using Windows Script Host, which is built into Windows XP and later (as is the "Microsoft Compressed Folders" support).

For instance, [Peter Mortensen's answer](https://superuser.com/a/112094/401839) shows the contents of a batch file that can be made, which writes out 8 lines of VBScript which then utilize the "Microsoft Compressed Folders" support.

Note that the "sleep 2000" at the end just pauses 2 seconds, and isn't nearly as safe of an approach as [George Yockey's approach](https://superuser.com/a/360524/401839) (checking for active compressing) or checking .Count (something like [kayleeFrye_onDeck's submission](https://superuser.com/a/1217040/401839)).

I'm not sure if a WSH-based answer violates the goals you intended when you said you didn't want PowerShell, but that indeed does not use PowerShell at all.