# Using .bat to convert ANSI to UTF-8 in windows

Tags: batch-file, csv, utf-8, ansi

So, I have o convert a .csv file from ANSI encoding to UTF-8 in windows, using a .bat file. Basically a program capable of doing this conversion without needing Notepad++ nor excel and etc. Do you have any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Oh thanks! But I never used powershell, so is it okay to just insert that line of code in a .bat file?

Comment: Something like that but see answer here with example of how to do it: https://superuser.com/questions/1237747/windows-in-built-compression-command-without-utilizing-any-external-tools/1237962#1237962