# How do I zip all files within a specified location only through batch code?

Tags: windows, batch

I want to make a batch script that will compress all files within a path I specify into a `.zip` archive with a name that I specify. I **do not** want to use third-party software as I'm making this tool for public distribution, and would like to utilize components that are built into Windows. I have a script I'm using now based on a question I found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili/112094?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Here is the code for my script:

```
:TESTCHOICE
ECHO Do you want to make a backup first?
ECHO (Enter Y to proceed or N to cancel)
set /p :CHOICE=""
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" GOTO :BACKUP
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" GOTO :MENU

:BACKUP
    SET FILETOZIP1=%FILE1%
    SET FILETOZIP2=%FILE2%
    SET FILETOZIP3=%FILE3%
    SET FILETOZIP4=%FILE4%
    SET FILETOZIP5=%FILE5%
    SET FILETOZIP6=%FILE6%
    SET FILETOZIP7=%FILE7%


    SET TEMPDIR=%TEMP%
    RMDIR %TEMPDIR%
    MKDIR %TEMPDIR%
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP1% %TEMPDIR% /Y
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP2% %TEMPDIR% /Y
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP3% %TEMPDIR% /Y
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP4% %TEMPDIR% /Y
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP5% %TEMPDIR% /Y
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP6% %TEMPDIR% /Y
    XCOPY %FILETOZIP7% %TEMPDIR% /Y


    ECHO Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments > %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO InputFolder = objArgs(0) >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO ZipFile = objArgs(1) >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar) >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source) >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs
    ECHO wScript.Sleep 2000 >> %TEMP%\Zip.vbs

    CScript  %TEMP%\Zip.vbs  %TEMPDIR%  "%ZIPFILE%"
```

Can I just implement a `FOR` loop to recursively zip the seven files within the specified directory, instead of declaring each one individually? If so, how should I integrate the method into my script?

Comment: your vbscript fragment already **expects** a folder as first argument. so if all files are already contained in one folder there is nothing more to do. Otherwise proceed but don't remove your `%temp%` folder. Instead create a random folder inside of `%temp%` you can `rd /S/Q` afterwards.

Comment: I can give you a batch code that *creates* a 3rd party tool (works without internet) called 7za.exe. This means it is pure batch code but creates a 3rd party tool in a few seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure how batch code can compile an binary executable, but I'll give it a try @Mark Dodsons.

Comment: Check out this code I helped write: https://github.com/ITCMD/Into-Batch

Comment: When compiling it, you can't have spaces in the name atm.

Comment: I can work on something for you tomorrow l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option does use a 3rd party tool known as [Kzip](http://www.advsys.net/ken/utils.htm), but it stores it inside the batch file using [Into-Batch](https://github.com/ITCMD/Into-Batch). It has a few options you should look at in :Setup to modify to your needs.

The Code:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Setup
Set FileInput=Integer
set CompressedFileName=Test
Set CompressionAmount=0
Set FileSpeed=Small
::Set FileInput to Integer to use this code like this: 'call zip.bat "File1" "File2" "File3" "File4"'...etc or set it to a text file. Note you can also copy entire Folders. This Will also Skip the menu
::CompressionAmount means how compressed it is, 0 is most compressed, 4 is uncompressed. More compressed takes longer to compress and decompress, but uses the least amount of space
::Set IndividualFileSize to Small if you dont want to use too many System Resources.

::NOTE! IF you don't want to use an external file or integers, keep it set to integers and uncomment the following 2 lines and add your files:
::call :BeginFile "File1" "File2" "File3" "File4"
::exit /b %errorlevel%



:BeginFile

::Here it tests if KZip.exe exists. If it does not, it will create it. You can add "Del /f /q Kzip.exe" to the end of the file before exit /b if you don't want it to leave the file behind.
if exist "kzip.exe" goto 21518947220390217462362419401 
(echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----)>temp.txt 
( 
echo TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4AAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5v 
echo dCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1vZGUuDQ0KJAAAAAAAAADFsydRgdJJAoHSSQKB0kkC 
echo +s5FAobSSQICzkcCgNJJAu7NQwKK0kkC7s1NAoPSSQKB0kgCrNJJAuPNWgKE0kkC 
echo bvB5AoDSSQJSaWNogdJJAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQRQAATAEDAA7jIEYAAAAA 
echo AAAAAOAADwELAQYAAEAAAAAQAAAAsFwBUPJcAQDAXAEAAF0BAABAAAAQAAAAAgAA 
echo BAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAQXQEAEAAAAAAAAAMAAAAAABAAABAAAAAAEAAAEAAA 
echo AAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXQHUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo ALBcAQAQAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAAAOAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAwFwB 
echo ADQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAADgAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAABdAQACAAAAOAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAkCAWjK7qlgHhA5 
echo ctNcAUgyAAAAUAAAJgEAWf////+hkMePAYXAdQHDi1QkBI1MJAhRUlD/FYhQQACD 
echo xAzDkPfvd/+B7DQCAAChQA9Tg8AgVaMvi4QkQBX///9/M9KD+AJWV4lUJCgPjZ4A 
echo AABoaGBAAOip////aiVowM/X3XwLnWgUYRWTCSiJPM/zPEx/aHWg6z7P82vsYRhi 
echo O1cJ53me52hNuEPwbvN1nzlAYycvCYxomATf7f7d6CAOg8RAagH/FTy/vgGiO8bH 
echo RCT93f+7EBj/iRXQdEAAiRXkfFAF3NycAQ+OqN/s7t4ii6wkTNyLPTgzuwTrAjPS 
echo i9/9//9EtQCKCID5LXQYgPkvdBM5VCQQD41gL4l0JBDp/7v//wEAAp4PvkgBg8G+ 
echo g/k4D4dHGDPSipHQHkAA/ySd+//dlawGikACPE50EzxudA/HBdBuIgBhL+tiOJEo 
echo DAXUG/5n7jAFcIQqikgChMkPhehr+MDuEMcF2CiDwAK3NLPm3G+43R1geoPEBMcF 
echo 9CEqO7L3bmwh1xeFwH4RzxDuwf5/O8N9MYtMtQCDwQJR/yEUi1QQ7/1h5MICUqMf 
echo 63THBQdR///u9+toiR0L62CSgPlTjVACdAWA+XN1E4pIAwv2O/yEyXUMxwVY1us9 
echo Q43//zf26zAvTCxsdSOAeAMxdR2AeAQydRczGLr/gHgFMXURikgGPgoinT7hf0PH 
echo bEiPRjvwD4x0/v//i78I7g+/hcB9FWjg4zz9///S4////3+LXCQQi0ydAI1UJDyQ 
echo jWQkAIoBQYgCQoTAdfaKTP+++/8kPDPAhMl0IopMBD1AZPeFwHQVKUqKDAIa/t/w 
echo gPlcdN8vdANIdfCNRAQ8ai5PMOm7m26DxAggeopEP9KEwHQ1JTve8L88D77AjXC/ 
echo geb/DIP+Gn0ig8Dv/v3YnyUO+Bp9Bbq6ikEBQXrThdJ17/5/9x+KFfyvg8n/M8CN 
echo fCQ88q6LDfgQT4kPiO/+A/ZXBOscGKEAZEAAig0EBU+JB4jc/8P/TwToAQAu/Iu0 
echo JAaNVv872nUNaAYd7obf7RcvjPyNQwE7xokWD43hjvuf0fCzIItMBYTGBIiAOEAP 
echo hacYtOl+t2gAlEBoAIAAANqki+j9d7Hf5IP9/w+EkB8gaKDYjwFV/xWg+79/8x74 
echo M8CF/35iOJgXfw5AO8d88x7/3/+mnOtbO8d9SIvwOJ4bfgVGO/d8842Qc499fwxS 
echo xoYGAKKNRgGlK5BuArsci/9HE1S4sQ8u9gZQNDHpi4z2/N907EA7weCMIbqh9CVS 
echo AIXAfxVoCHSXMD4FOfsCPREMoazhtOEbtW2hPudk/MN3CXuNRCT/3oP4/3RHDh2/ 
echo NzzQ2EBRaBhU5PppNff/37mY5SP/1oP4G3RMg/hOdEeD+G50QlDH/9twBz3gMnUC 
echo G1l0BYP4eXXYS3vXud1Sfw+svX0vbzxQaEBQ9zAc5pNJqGhgFPduyMh+BH88UWh4 
echo GXDnXs1koQkzbQoPMeuPNTRmMAMs/TPthcCJbIIea/i/jvgHAABqAI2UJETcVX0M 
echo oej/u/+b941c7QDB4wKKTBggwvbBEIlcJBx0OYobujvcFY5fhLwkQDG5T//yvzOw 
echo +65miw2MFk+N2RVmiQ9QiFf2u2K4AspgpQ2nagGNjGS7u253URcPDHJMKlJokDjo 
echo tL7pf4f5L3eLBB6LDdi8g8QUA8Fmm/7nJWaKCECICkJz9oph7RzJmkcYhPyCoaz/ 
echo FPvfSGaJR/+LfB4EAz1CLvKu99Erpj/Y7vmLwSWL90+L+ovQM8BE736w/8rB6QJP 
echo 86WLyrmD4QNosEdQ86T/b+BhwxUsvovwQfalJA+E3H/v/voGAACDPbcEdTbFENyL 
echo DbNWiUTb/Y//GQhVxgWgbkAAszJcVv8VKD1otEuBP/C46Nf4YeUNp90FXfHvv/vc 
echo Hbgd3+D2xEF1bosVQ4tEGhR3cATXRyQX/aPgWA+EknviP3NyZItUGRRWagFeICRH 
echo cJ2harZlHAqvxwXv37/jpJ98UgAAi0wYFFFqhzUcixVG4Rl491L/FVAng8Qo6xkn 
echo eXy7H6MAH4XAD4S6Nmi4qS3//7vXoR+Cg/gBfkqNSP8z/4XJflO+mD1S//v9+wCL 
echo /4H+B3QNaNAu/vfYBIsWUmjU3x3MfA/uPghHOoHGGAoA90u+/wA7+XzI6xJo2CHM 
echo BFBo4BLM93fJuQhzDWjsFqJwMfPthWjwDJWuEV+8+e7ODGj0FX/rEIsVXYPf/Tbd 
echo wiDlfIsVwDPAKjvQo4i3uX7CxI8BIMt/o5ib+L+DNwMUD44UEjP2vZAzUgC7CDhS 
echo ocvwQdUDD42BGTgoF/+vbrOFo7gIBLnejb0ABQAA86uTc3ffuAkRcASNu8hGEUP9 
echo c+5/AI08tZA8UgC5GhgSNokEtfh1hpPOEgb8AEMNBEXTud8GM8mJDLUICAYMuDrT 
echo ue4pGxALBhRRGI051+0GuRxRuHp7NYi6NrnOFDWMBlkKojY0nev46fsQRCQ0RIAK 
echo /os7dne7/fkYHtH/FYQSBQCeiQf7f8N33hiDxwRICRh15TPJi9OJColKBG51u5ih 
echo EAkycY2bBAD/qTuQOLg+WD2dfRmNDAaNn/jfwzyNTbkQK8gzwPOrP2oQ3abvw42V 
echo NlJohlUzETwThfBr94aARFCNjYD1ah4QETzoYMKft4PEIOtQdGcAsZ3hQ3THg4hq 
echo NACNCc417GIhsZQ6cn+pbkV4t+E8tZRmuT8NM8DHBI52f7z7MfOr8RRAgcWMgcaG 
echo SIHDu4s3/As7wgIUD4z/BI2kJDf/N/y/AIXSfi++oNiQAb+QC4vqM8CLz4oRiBQG 
echo 93tn4kCDwfXxfPCBxzyBxulB+kH3TXXdXBBzFMyn0zcZ/lwkIItECxSAOsB+TYst 
echo r7uJ/4RPK8eL8IH+ACh2Bb4GOxLf1DYkUmoBVjf/1Qf3R9owJh681YtEAxSBxyg+ 
echo Hnf/g8QYO/h8vxorXKHIoQx26Azsy6HsrQyPsIITd/8PdCQci3wODItEDhBxfCQg 
echo IXRw6H8Ci8c7RA4UfiGhWV4Y2Qd2TeckfxBR9jJcO+T+Y67uNkQODDvHD46q8kF4 
echo t4vSYY5XDL7Q3JcdIDjaxeiLjYvPqB93XAg/iVH8fO0i2qYNRYuZu+GnFYuB+gDz 
echo D41SSnA/3f3fi6xEMRCLfDEMkSCLLb8rxzv/Hbj6wY0clZheeBSJA30jjUytACYY 
echo uOHB4QazIIvBt6fuDTTwjsDIufOkjUQi/oOn/+AGg+gCjTyVkPoHoHg8g87/ixt+ 
echo hM8zyYqIod4z24qR/x/6v5ABweEEA8szzoHheYsMjcDYlQHB7gj/v6PdM/FCedIO 
echo FIk3jUL/hcB8aIs/jUn3f//3ADs8hVZ1C4sTOxSFnXQFSHnp60ohWMJ/R0YJIDkD 
echo fnqF7X4wJnB4lfBCIscF04DpQNcUAEUk3Mf++Afh3CRUJCiLRBEIaBDsoRDrIR1J 
echo LxBA5DAYbNhjCsw/JFF69oThJj4iXPJXbCQY1Rw4Eo/4RTvo94wI6W7iBl4gTkYP 
echo MRDw60aB+R4kHVJo+Dsgix0ujkYQ7AF4D+xpsAj8D2gQZUAA6P/x/hRy0DX8i3wk 
echo OMw0KS148BhNH2UzyVA5yYPAFOnr/98/AwiDwCRKdfiFyYlMJBR0Hm1keIDfd7+h 
echo kJN8APeo93wkFLoRK9Aw399vN2olUlGLDRxRaCBzi/+GbjAJFLobLSyLbCQwK/Ab 
echo +Hfm+/1XVmhYI2exX15dM8BbgcTr/rsOgcN7yRFAAEISQACgB2oDrmuapuuRr3IX 
echo ogNg/3/ZAAgAAQgIAgMECAgFCAgGBxYBzqawH5AAoZn8N+y4hcBTOQhWDBBXdQXG 
echo AwDrOtwv/ifGjQT2iwSBAwWci9OTsfu/LNiAOwB0FGaLFXjBi/t+2b9wrJ9miVf/ 
echo OXyBBKE3Fm93HAP4HtjRDpLFu3iL94v7zUQkGIvRvIH/mxCFwPOkdAhTU/8VsP5f 
echo XlvDSeoHNi4EaFhoAYPGH/7/DSuD+P+jmLB+AHUDM8DDM8CjcaOU4GYfDZO4ksPc 
echo BXV8R9jbEBysiw0vUG2od8rB21uLFQ2FB0/8d8IwMbuhSTvID46i4XW8N+pqAFCh 
echo LN9gOd3/dz8WIY1R/zPQPPfCAADw/3RNJf//sf/f/Q8AVos1jCa5AAAQACvIUY2Q 
echo 4HxAAEBMs1lDCdZffcQZiP3tL1FoIFL/1qU1b2zmjsZewzuyVQUkf7v3e7xbixXu 
echo eIkVqMOJDRsW62IG7pBEzBBsCYeY/0QhHTjxrweQkLpHVovCuf///3dk3z7mAffe 
echo geYgg7jt0egzxkl17EqJO/q/6wSVxGd52F7Dg+wQU1UzwEAkDP8du13YEFdgE5zQ 
echo KDPbM/aF7Q+ONvRNhjiAWSSB7/AcgYS34t1N/waFwH4W6xADwQUU0/hDrufg5zIX 
echo 6wv3CPXwfwfff1ZLzIZGO/V8xoP7Ag+M6/+d+99/jVwr/jvri/V/QJ8iFDyL+Ik0 
echo vYgq7+/v2VIADRSFQYk0hRIDFL0N/8+691aJFLUHIRNS837DM/+NQ/87xe+x3e+J 
echo PJ0afB5Piww1ixSNEvg3/dlCiUtIO8V95RIsjU3/O898Q/f/fjt0JL5dgeoFjQSL 
echo K/ONaQE/z8C/C0iDPBEAfhSLCY1Df2fi/0E7z4kIfgqL+esGB7+D6ARNddc7/RP8 
echo +3wkMHxW/Yt0JBAu0+ID8kHdBl5NqBBaDhFNGiyI330Dfs2L/vOruRQ8iRyGobvv 
echo dmC2zITWS4XbD4XOB1/Hf5/+hgZmAF5dW4PEECQkvQ+DwwTXQUMDLRyYMIQYn27g 
echo hjtwMIsBfm47bJHdfSb/u7/ryxAVFAPC0/iL/3EkizSeA/LT/jvw72743XUJDihD 
echo O9586HD9fToOGI1F//+7YPE7x30nbz0siwyCixY7yn4On2D3DfYsiVSFAAcciSrg 
echo Rz3hOv6DxgQ7+3zKATArsihm+P0YKgP4RQPQS8GJCaXEXIY/VCQYD4xb+fjHv/su 
echo dq+4PyHHBewlUuUAgKMEJlKM5+juAKMABMcFiPsUv/9MYyW4VXMdRovG0U/48Pf4 
echo ixSFL4sslY1Xi+w775ON/d+JNSKLzn4biRSNIcgsOc8R+5E8f+VfiRwblXm/A2Z4 
echo jGNxUaEXU1U2/Dv2VleLPU8svUtPg/8CdRCJ7/8jxBTdfFSNZCQAjQwSiwSNMxgf 
echo 49iLNFmLBK0z2zsEoGeD/feLBK2nD5zDA8siORl9+6b/9w+JNJVci9EDyTvPfrTG 
echo EF9eiSwUG97wHl1bWZbJBIHsBPxWVx8BdvyJDcTclQE3ENyijQzJif9Is/dEigih 
echo FhHmZokNqG5AAG73f4DH/lBLAwRmxwWkEBQACH/A/pumAgCNBMCITIIhOY0MwI0M 
echo irr/d/9mi1EcZokVqiRmi0keagFQjVQkEFJRrIZoYOcSeg8M3TPydKbrgBTHSRm6 
echo FI0Rcs9MKBKjvBERc0nI/Y10JBS/vg0QKD3fOeAvg8EdUWijWBZMg8QUZ7OYcwfb 
echo 5s/hDMPVd/zHBcRvQABJ/8cFnGY0J2gXzIWgCTUb7Pz/jscTiw34WF9IO8heagF9 
echo BGoA6wJqu+AuPjAWvG9qAmoBFrydGqlnJWnJNcFXx8HwT/AXHIHEEGd1qNx1RzAC 
echo B3wkEPn/fhmI/+J/ixAzwIoEHvUWfIPEBB+BZO8i7VtfXjSfilQkBMADn8CLyP5A 
echo iJHai/3gEYjJpCvCPTt8Bb1nyXYSEBw5cIsN377/dzdZBKGY3tPiC8IDTCQIg/kI 
echo ow+Jj81mxx58KoAsKIPpCCF7Ye7B6AiRKX3WX0d3v+GB7KQ7U1WLrCSwCIuFdP32 
echo rgZ4hcBWuw5XVBB1I40U+obPKh+B+wETfguLSPy/v7/v50uFyXTtJIuN9DfJjYUH 
echo vh7msJ92SnUUD4P+ASxOTe+x//CNg//+//9qBbC8jUYKSChd8R8Ms5QQhfZ+GY3g 
echo hXf13wB6i9aLOIk5g8AE3Ep187uhw/0D3jPAuRNbWxyD2/OrfKD/zL0UD44Yk5+N 
echo TgE7y30U3/8jZf5POUSNAHUFQTvLfPUTK9Puv6vOV2GD+QN8XIH5ikl+F2W/4btv 
echo ZLkKQIdkjXQO/4cY9YP5Cn67rlv2Df9EJBGaGkP8QRKDZF2y7/kGfx1cLypgDHf/ 
echo +7sqODtEtfx1Mmppi8GZvwZs9/+Duw0m+PoCdQW5K9JcQkaJVP+73/skXH4FuR4+ 
echo 60cxfjeLfIQcjUSEHLM/BPZHiThJPQPx6wuLTDY3/Yf/QYkIRjvzD4zuawiNTCRs 
echo UbckahPH3d8ASBE8jUQkLFAVfGoT6Qf/YdMbahy+V7hYYEAAiy74uxt+lGiFyXUL 
echo 4U49HBJ/641G/GoEf+g2TbQ6M//hH9+LDL0Q+w/vdyCLVIxoagNdxQhHO/585ST/ 
echo 7zK82w+Okpq0FI1fAYvzO/F9D4tEB39u+L0AOUS1lUY78b0AK/fvH3a/YYWWIYP+ 
echo Aw+MjQiB/pJ+B/cz/r++BusFg/4KfimLhKNMJGRQt3/4Yf8WvI1W9WoHdRCNfDe7 
echo GwaF/1z3H9x+I2apG4P+Bn8WOahUJ90H64dcOWoC6xQVrGB/AvshA41W/U9TO0S9 
echo /HXhCL+xTZ+gNMaZs/f50oSPHRm+lCRlRCRcUiqwj3CXf34Fvt5O/WoCt2b4u12p 
echo 62tMfleLVIRoi+kx2YfKXk6LWzP/6w9Wh+PvWOcURzv4D4xuFH3/9Dd8GIXSfCYR 
echo EI0ECo2MlW6NRIUAQrjjYPGLMIkxyOkEAUp17Z/6X5+vgcQow1WL7IHsn7gfob/7 
echo DwX/SMdEhYQJAHX1U4tdDG//J32XPIt1CHwXj4sMhotUjYCNTJ2Ljv+NgEpIiRF5 
echo 77kPAPMUK///3/3CA9DR4IkJQYP5IHzshdt+NleLfRAr/osGhcB0/453/yOLTIWA 
echo iUUMlYCJTQjTi1UIi00MM8Bd3cX/0eoTwEl1+YkEN31LddE4i7WJP9blXdmh8Nyc 
echo AVNtw1dU7/0YRlYzyccFFHf7/5H4IjPAr9PiiTTFtLWPAYkMxbAGDRD7vwPyqAF0 
echo DIP4AnwHH90D+6+7/8pAg/gefM+/A+Izybr7uKC2jwFIbPf/H9PmiXgEiQgD/vbC 
echo A3UOPdgXfAcZ7/7/XTv2A86DwAhCPYC3jwF80LgCfr6X2I/vu9/uAaOEEIkdFrk6 
echo VSvwizzNhrvo//+IDAYz0kg7xw+cwivKg/gDfee4yb7nADsU+xxRALkdKd8scXcT 
echo fzvDf+heuA1/uf9mv+R0auDOPezgBTWA86s0AG5T/Jvuv+h8UADzq7lkv/BVG95j 
echo 0POrKwN9MyLVv5B3d/Hdk3oig8j/o8haiR2csYkdwG5iQ3cLiB2Mj6PId4kd6P+J 
echo I+E9YGnANFOJHZiTfDZx1/0AiR2gtX4F1HmJHfB5iR1zP7Eh+4kdhceAgECl0DvY 
echo wOsdnJpfW8OQir/vyFl0EIveadtJV427gHsXQ6QXkxA9Uo+/q6PfIxS/ABAAAL8K 
echo mAmJPIWon/jYJ/x8AOsQiyy76YksEUCDwgTsTfF/sdiD+Dt9RGn2SwPwjRQcBOM/ 
echo YY3ojTS1HDxSAJ/O8f93aXUEiTrrBospA+iJKoPBCFNFwER3wYH5w3zfoU32fcBv 
echo 8kS/oNiVAW26e08/PUj9bmyLyH0YizIvOTSN3/3v+B18BtIefPGIDAdAjUj/T4P5 
echo HnzS6xUv/migsH4AjZNib2pYNNz0G0yZIGggOmpIi8fpgY4YctBjF/839QhVcBBW 
echo M8CF7Vd+LIsN+x+pboiwGIvxoMHpCDPM1R3x1osUlRwzykDxI///N3F82iPtfi2L 
echo /YH/AH4AAH0ohf+Lx34dDbyfxVCNsR88gcYX0IGL39i/7wg79XzVeLgN69eC/138 
echo sIsN2YPsKCJsJDiF7VZXdQT//zf8i9HrOX4ftzyLwSvxi/2KHAaL0IHi//8AAEA9 
echo 9nf3T4iaqMp166EGA82JQI2R/HrG43d1o6i1fwChDDeLgBN/wyasO8jfIIlMJDx8 
echo BIIw+/9xPIs9Rjv6D41VCgAA6w0PcYehg1+Lz0bkixSN3y4W++CNBAYVfYupdMeH 
echo u/9HGX+LxcH4DCvFWxiLFcQG3nX/Jf8PAACD+gNpNGcwD41plu5fw+MPvjXYT5E7 
echo i9qB40iP/T/+ADvedRyLNe1Ggf7/fwAAiQx+Fb5IZ+8/6wgz9ogVNxaLESb9N/1m 
echo iTRN0CqNTwE72X8Ii9koGT7gE0I72X1/87LTs//bYDiWbXUFQzvZfOsngT1tJpOj 
echo 3QBffgrWeb7/uZ2hANMJi/c2hQy1mLB8/t1/+gAPvwxFzYvHK8FIJTEAQIXAiXQk 
echo LP8Owi451yuKi5JiM9X3wj517k10AA+ErU44TfqL0DR0fMA6O8J/yYMsFBwZ3t8d 
echo EByLFYiLHI1qBA399d/Si8IrwzvGiQSNIA+P/eyofwP/6wGLNRh0GmaLHF1BAIvu 
echo K+hmOx3w3d8cbQsPhdkjg+D+D4QOixF6n/3aK9gr8I0njTR1Ip+aPv3+iys7Lg+F 
echo iyvoAnnDBGzpePfBhoImNaxku4vLK8/8dx9utBCLDcaFyegcupjXjwEPhErdf8N3 
echo CivXg8L95hS56JxQAEm6/TIrRvfuwNe+sjVAjW8DHCQ/PtIfG9sPvgwBiwypZokE 
echo Vf2biP2NQokZGBQPvhQqixyVd46/O8cOGAPLA8qL1d5rjRyV++v/H3Y7C30vO2wk 
echo PH8pOy3tfgaJB+/4PxYm/wMAweICZomysO1miYKyZvqDdwaJC4H+Ag+Ekwcmw/0j 
echo fQAAiiqLzyvIjRQxYBd3jv/YEnRqO3QkEHUS6xMz0mZwrzvGixRZA8KQJDAZhO8J 
echo 7w4D1TsUko1DVwyy/cH/fTPSA84xqrWPAAPCPUUPjyPDDa/sH2l1lvFARkVwMW74 
echo cCIMuTMr0S4oixRopu5ndAokDitUJCQNFPUwPMb/FI1R/TvWfDaLNSdsJBRE/Idj 
echo R9JGiRJFvokPvlwG/07+u4c3rECLNJ1MiSnrIYsslaCbfAC62L/AIjv1fQeJNCDp 
echo KP//uRqJCtc8A9YDVCQYjTQPi+6B5Rz78AfmOxStio0sBn02HwvCNzE8fyo7NY8H 
echo i/6B50dOmof/j+ePh1UAbjjhWVaB+ZaR3A++q04bTAfjaXSKnj0Hwo6bEiyL97kU 
echo Dp8PwmuE3YTTLztMo+b3o2GS4TR1/aOCn3LuSL+Ncf07NJUzjQ4xy4OM8H9TM/YD 
echo 0WaLNFWgxu77v+lMnvNAAjvqf4mLXCRAipWQv2/i/4oEAzrQi/V/EP8PvvKKlhQ6 
echo 0KGBf/h+84s0tRqD+QV+FgmIVvtq9785MH4Lg+kDg+gMFX/xTBkaQ7tIppBvHwlJ 
echo 1d7wTjsYf/P0xNNAdSmLG2ua7bYz2+bSVczDnbn33Qfk+///mQY71X1dKCaHuUH+ 
echo 31n9OxzCId/b5g6bPBxBoh9Bu/s3fQ+Nt6PrhYP9HQ+PixaLNK3H7w59x4Mk4IsE 
echo 7Q0LI00Pvnj3b9OQ59KAuvAeD41fK4F8JBAOG4J9snUWhqsz9k3FdsHGr8YVnIE8 
echo mR0b5t4fAA+OJDqdLa637txBMBx7jhmPcSEsQVlnde0FIz+BHtyL8YZIz/qL1ivw 
echo H4k0Yjn0wcHrMIkV/ojfiRXAI2A6MHWXZokU4x8EjmZmiadMJDQzwIqBUuCHA8PX 
echo kKVHibEIEsfpi/ASrPGLD/3GweACi6gEi4gngc3HfzzbF4CJEccl+QPLjRyF+x/u 
echo +/87C38oO/p+CIvXiRVQix/t4IJj/PMCZseAAQBmibDvC4v9h/+/zoP7AnQohdt0 
echo Co2PRDvKfhqLLXfEDg6pDsUFVj0AAJjtvvsEAA+M13U71w+O0QfrCjwkHhIH73/3 
echo x3rGntTAbH8xi47ewWdF4id2wYvPbqaDPelI/PsDfWIPvjAz21mL6/w0sTPGXDvq 
echo aBVCgfreHRkeyUljfhW6DGE2oyZo0nkWWOBmPZJkM9KJ+BYewRF7nv4EfUc7+jyE 
echo ByeK54APjGk3wURFb9aF64z/OhvhPTMV/iUnM8lmi/v/+sMMhTmLx4v3uivBO8J+ 
echo PYvITslx7HeDWossjR2NDAaL3ib+uXMsFYksnTPbZosZJz/iPfbCf887PA+PFWeE 
echo i9a/d6bDacngODFmiwSVMmY9//A+9gEAjSwKdTEzwBauA8iLBIU4Y/xHK8HhAv+B 
echo DJG/25EMJKcpgrMAAA++uJW/ngMTC5k5hxON/9R9xwQ5Rf+AHDdSHrJDA87/BI3+ 
echo jzYBPouA/IsMvSy0fgC/Jj4D9osU/QIBf0UAFDHg9FIrBP2BwcezR48biwS1n8ED 
echo zvP9PdgpmI2LDPU9izz1XT967DaAUSvX2ha8WWAHP/zwg8QgoWlGO/BRD47rikhx 
echo aIQUoel44nv46DuBC6OMfHoqjz+r54Yd1wACAAC/8hhNKNLzqyxTRSTeYBhXazvI 
echo xwShw8hER1mA/VL1R//7TCQgOQ1OD4yt9f//5IPEKJ8ZBjNgTaAMTVNWVwRDsOH/ 
echo gJA4i4AuIatNPToVtShp0qZtAo7wjZKTyr5iiwENd8A3MwCAdQjHHgDrB5b/JOX4 
echo /3+JAYPBBE514moQaNDP7uG7WewRPHJsHFB0QAAFmPwcndT8Ef5qizVfw2wDOYvH 
echo J0K5RQXdrv8fBIsRixgr2g+vmADTiRBmAx9gF/3zg8AEgfk4fOGXRzs31O/Y+IlB 
echo iT1NfU23HZyL6I85gA26gIPEBEk7wT2LBRIV8u+BwivD/+F40hccg8QMX15bOh3d 
echo dwC/kJCD7AxWDOgBAB88BCoH4HfFHKGw99iD4AdQnHisYtAWvFWSjRTABHL/AWz3 
echo 0YlMkBgv3l1BsAEQMHWN/zvo/wTAi1SBGI0EgYkVGYtQDItIECvKiQ3fQd9BwYtQ 
echo FIkV24tACIPALBn0jw43EOxqDENJfgh+5BUMwItEigkQ7Iv//9iDU4qNFMmLdJAQ 
echo jQSQK3AMixV2bHAAcm6F0qsMxgH//4kyAHRgVmh8ZUAA6K7T//8cju94zgmFwA+O 
echo smaK/w3xpqCFyQ+FIIvI99mD4Qdryf/fffZ9UYvICI0U9SYAK9DB+gNSUcH4A1Bo 
echo ww1vvpRMYYPEFF5Qw4sV7rvoAP6F0n9ji0A2J3gEx38HDuBEJAhpbAz3bCQI93zY 
echo MoDZJAS4gMNHcP/3aiVSxkyQFFFWaKxcAf8VCbg79kRQQAAKaMQU6O/SD4M+Qqwg 
echo cb2QkIHs4wQ0mKpTiorQ0NCb6oPZM8k7w+4Q/4+Z3gUID45YWmhVVzPt9kQoIBAP 
echo hRY1NRXSQWIUV3ITug8BArkU6GaaBuj//y5ailQoITPJgPoID5TB9tlqAVaD4Yvc 
echo X2SKj2YPthxdfRe5D0woHDNWZotUKB7Unf3fF65uQACLTCgYiQ2wCQwYEMP9/3af 
echo FbQPRCgUjUwkJFGjuA1KOvZkkYoo8q6t99G0y0Uuj32ViR2cdO5deGaJHcAuBsLE 
echo 7/7/zqQgg8n/jXwkKI10JCiJFcYUi0QoCP3HANyjygjISYvRwekCv84uCvbfEPOl 
echo i8qD4QPzpDPlrtiy6IPBLbp9+xewoakkXCjjixVs6MAbfkaDxSQ78lEQD4y3Ax7u 
echo IezQX10+BQaU1LmH4eAGOQzZBozwO0N93xDcK8JqFs6j3MEdPiaJFRYtDR9BLLqh 
echo MQheW7VvIm7YHw/s41aLNbFoAIcAqe8M7wDHBYWiCeTcnAHA7o8/3bX/1giFwKMh 
echo dRVoyCaCQyjOyNC1aD0S0ZndpZ+9xwXgmYBhzzsTO/KEWsjTO+CMCDcUP5eLAoHs 
echo x1OLnCj+G4okXIoDVVZXM/8zyfH/Y2QunzxcdAQ8L3UCi/mKRBn/t/tXXe2LNaB6 
echo iw12jUQ+ATvBfn8B7/9DA8k7yH4Ci8FQoxV0UP8VM9hIjkjumaOS+MeeJez5z85O 
echo 6wU0M8n9/99BK4oUGQPGgPpcdQbGBAgv6wOIFAh//z+LHSpBO8983QPGxgQ4AKGJ 
echo jVQk+O7v/xRSjUw4AVOL6IkNEf8VFHmL8IP+//zdTUfdhKkvix0AFPZEJBQQdDD/ 
echo d58Qdg+EdBmAfCRALnUcikQkQc3TvfuEwA+EYRI8LnUMD0JRi2D4h4cNqqGlO8gP 
echo jPu0YeA9QmbR4KMUFmGZCzDhH/PCEHsl+w+EOT0Rnj4EIjVqBNh9iSyQGwhSxQ9T 
echo GCQ0pu8W9olEihQVkBSIRIogZShm76IoPyxS/9Mh/L8B91SDlo1QHFKDwB5QjUQk 
echo MLqqyTWCBPMWMxFATPjYnxhJi/GLhY1EMQHEwoeHNMA3ixWqUFLH0u4jIcEPhID4 
echo 6w9OO5ywI9Ew95YVdJUnJAO6QAPQ/5tMHE742TABonQkEECdo0ppA+4jtFb/FQif 
echo uYVkfx+/MJ0ODAyBxJbDO2Fs4GgQZuXIzTBoKBT4eyzks8sDgewMGP7ofnCEJBQG 
echo U83bU1MHP8H9QBm0JCwVuI0s9sGg4U/85QKLVCkIRhDsM8Amv3CZkvXSrGNdc9YJ 
echo AaCJHQsdwAZG+IhcKCELSXckZkfgdcAbMh4yagHXy8ANhCxWUDofElwRLgESNItM 
echo sWZJAJ0S1gBdB1xEJfw0iA2sIJ7hKRy4IQGcJF8yOGj2MQqJRCkM5jqgJjpXn+gU 
echo Q1x//RsawpzEi0wpFCvLgfk3i/lyIt7w2AW/CJQkJCBSagFXAOwixl4ViIPEoH9f 
echo jV9Hb6FMM8mKjuq7V5huZEzB6AiL2ftZcWd6CjPTi/fQUYkVLNxDANyWisGLgHX3 
echo 98+Yi0QpFIHDdTvYiRUPjGnDwh1zul730L+MHUToTkUOEGdvGGbwDxZ3TCgQK0wo 
echo DNyFg2HhF3glEx4sgXl1VCkQ73D8DmZPs2olUFBoQFIMYhIRyaMw+/8O/iSFwHU7 
echo MhSNQQqFwHQTi/CQaGIp37HHuOg2y5FOdfA0aGQUIRePGSMIvoVFer/dP72LRCoU 
echo ZGhoJPzKOT1iDhqxXRgktUSm/pcDVYvsg+T4g+xt+pv6d76F0otNCItFDAWJDZQ9 
echo UgCj3XCAnpXHuqkAD484E9AFFTN2HElk6jdA/4l8JBC7nU9PvYH4hf8PjESL92n2 
echo KYt2bXq/hkWLlkaxIFECfFBdfOiGDFIDwa44bP6FT9G/i8DuHH5g3UQkINzd3+8Z 
echo fUB5T6+LlkNn70n9A1QkHIvBD4mQEVWJ2DvGvpBbixFBYAQAAIludwcG94m4nKOw 
echo PQ+Nn76kXPd3S4u+Eg+FVrmLuCv/LneXCw+MNRVlN6iD+gEPjhoMFKNw1AyOgHbv 
echo HhwAWivBaKBVUKFIxR7mtsIDBY5cbcC97qOQHqEu2LuNJkPu2dt4ixU0zaGkIFr8 
echo TR1EIE32I0QkJHw1i8oJ/zsCBoHBKd0B3FwkIAT8hg7+D4txBIsBVyQkIIvySoHp 
echo fRiEP1iF0n3ZYo4AK468Y6b/g4P5Ag+MtBfZi5aMhHcsITIriYgxMo+D8PeNgHAr 
echo ylCZA9Gvv9+z2ThsrJSJgUeLkWED0N+x2NiJkQ2GBXWJhk+NVw3CsZZJwVIcyOu7 
echo cPA6SL420DUDx1/9Y7GJNp2DxBhAO8GjkQ9wjMLAjNqPMNH6f+ZuyBMZD4SYx4Yr 
echo yjPbhT38XafJtvggfnSL+mn/BLi3oeGNd7cFHBwkFD0M3wEc6XwyRWQkzDE71n4S 
echo uf/f0IkwjhiJESveK8crz4XbfeaLY+8wQGMeTA5bdCQUQ46dBb0FVRXZb0QkvuNk 
echo x1Z8p5eFaCdfXjPAW9IlBat0TpBPu2/qHyxTVot1DEnAg/4BV0kcDzLteMeOm1E7 
echo 87kAEL+gnH/9Y6aLC2pAAPOrfiDvi1UIz777Xe0MEIs8jaAWR0A7xokKfOTv6m+C 
echo uQUzwL+YoHwAGygXbgUN//e7tQcstbiTRrot86uQiwo7yyMUsf+7+HQQ2e3be9nx 
echo 3ZiYqHwA6wyJB/COeu6JmJwNGZPACIH6xL9zf4LciJAVKZN8AHy83QW4d13D3xaN 
echo Rv87w9ntVxguGMIU2fHPdvz/20UM2cDZ7dnJ2fHYyd2j3dgtD473f9+9msoDAIve 
echo i0XETDj/3QTNoFLH7t5/3GQkINjBiwSN9TUwjTQXQN33rmn22IvQiRYREGcQjUIB 
echo cglqeDEKMAMrBb5z3a4QbgXolkAoTNnK3AXgh//u7w7eytnA3AXYCdjJ3vrZydwE 
echo zR73w97Z3RwG2FJP2MncFdnBPvanV0R7LN1P2MHZwkq8wx/kydnByt753CzNN0g5 
echo F/s7Gkgg3AxVZQiOMvzDFWRBS97BG7/u5rvuFN0WbiADFNnB2MzO3sHuezH39yDd 
echo BdCgwdjJOrZpzcAOJ+zec97FTit//4eH693YV9xsJDDcVCQo1AV6CF3/DbjdCpIc 
echo i0QkGEeNT/+BjHe4DaZtW2lVEATO3djZ49999+3dBciR2fHcPcAH3EwkKN0aX17Q 
echo v3tHAM9q/2jwJGhyTEAAZD/4+6ahkwBQZIklB4PsIChl6P9dA/SDZfwAZXAnWYMN 
echo CN2cAf+D9t3d3w0MBv8VbBSLDQQMiQj/FWgNhPs7MgChZAwAoxANd/dN37Y8bYM9 
echo kBcAdQxobmz/FZQf9ef+X1kZWGgMYEAAaAgEDlKh/Lq/+99NiUXYjUXYUP81+AyN 
echo ReBQjUXUA+TmdruGflg4aAQtaAAEMu7f3T3/FVQUi03ghXXg/3XU/3XkGL+pcv8A 
echo HIPEMIlF3DREi0XsiwiL+/8P8QmJTdD5PExZWcOLZej/ddD/FUw/7b4Zu/8lkAVc 
echo aAAAAwAEAQC7u7/bRzx0KTPAw8P/JXQb/yV4BczMqwrADiYDH6MI1sC/Q+oA8D+s 
echo /85B/UwuSOxfyUsa4D8miMCBiC7nGtjFoD+a/zA7RAMYnwqgMgIQAAAACNxnuhED 
echo EgIIBNc1EJgdhwYLCgOm6xooywsHBAMMQaZpmgMNAg7//zLX5A8HAnBAS1pJUCBb 
echo b3B0aW9u+df9+3NdIFsuD2ZpbGULQAcgb3Ig/yfs/3NwZWMuLi5dIABieSBLZW4g 
echo U2lsx1zs/XZlcm1hboZeJVpjcv//k/1lYXRlcyBXcyB0aGF0IGFyZSByb3VnaGz/ 
echo //7/eSAxLTMlYyBzbWFsbGVyHm4gInBremlwIC1leLD/Y7sgdCIKV0F2YWlsYWJs 
echo ZSCv/3+3ezoKAGcvcgRSZWN1cnNlIHN1Yi1kaXL/72L/ZWN0b3JpZXM3Hi92LHEg 
echo VmVyYm9zZf/u7P8sUXVpZXQgbW9kZT95IEFzc3VtZSBZ2He/c6qddGhlICdv0ndy 
echo aXRl//6x2P8/JyBwcm9tcHRSd3MjICBTZWz//3fvayBzdHLmZ3kuIDA6WHRyZW1l 
echo KGRlZmF1bP//7v90KSwgMTpJbnRlbnkgMjpMb25nZXN0IE1hdGNowx9zsSxMfgIz 
echo Okh1ZmZFYr/7fyBPbmx5LCA0OlVuY3JyZXNzZWQqGf5vxndiQmxvY2sgc3BsaXQx 
echo v4b/3yFob2xkIChsb3dlcj1tb11iIXMsg30Y+yAwPTEgCy/GLCCXPeF/LPYyNTYp 
echo /3tHb29kIHZhbHUAC4Lhv3RvIHRyeSAobwaPNNz9HwYptzogL2IxMjgsBjUxMt8d 
echo +/cwBDEwMjRPL26fRXhhY3Rjw274IG51bWLSb2Yg2Ylzz+5ucFtccmlkbS9iI4cv 
echo ch3+//9uICBSYW5kb21pemVkIGluaXRpYWwgdPK5BsfXMmeiZo4heaEFw/DfG3Mg 
echo d2l0aCBzYboTMf7uw0uACoBtcGxlOiAiScMQ7v5zYXZlICoiL2xsIFQ57jC+Y2Ug 
echo N3JlbnQgNXl43+D4DAEwLoN2QXByIDHf/Tv+NCAyMDA3AO0ncyBvZmZpY38gd2Vi 
echo IPr//45zIjogaHR0cDovL2FkdnN5cy5uZXQva2Q4i2AYWwRDySV1O95XZDogJZZO 
echo ZeFhFr93ct1uwiFrJ796AAC+44/xKgBOb31zIGZvdW4DJXMgYWwMw/+bU2R5IGV4 
echo aXN0cy4gT0qn7v0Jfz8gKHkvbgBFcnJvcmrsY3z6jnUZbm90IGI4ZW5KTzb9Jsdw 
echo ZbH0IGNhbmNleWQu91zf7X4AQ1t0aW5nIAc+E//O3fEvKgB3QWRkFxMtMTJzIEtT 
echo Zt1799hsYSgAAC+wcmIAACvrCvdP3xmbYrBhhDogAAAsIz7ju38leAAAbm9uZQoA 
echo ICglZJYAAHNvmWvqECniCkG3sa5/uWD0HxxvYyBmAd9x52K/ZwJUb3QgKGluY2y6 
echo 7/6/dZ0gaGVhZGVycymmOWQvJTljef+/+79+KCUyZCVjKaNUb29rICVJNjRkIENQ 
echo VT3D7/ggY3ljbIQoUkRUU0M6y4N1b9hYIEaqbGVuZ0g3RAC5h/3/IC0lN2QuJTAz 
echo ZCAtPiALCgBmLJh7gGoAJdjPvq6jwo4AF1P/Gg7ZHWE6KCCdIDAHIE72xhqRCJ8K 
echo 7CwlOGCG2MHrICgmeAIiLNiDOwoGKIIqoP//3QlwAABAAAABRmlsZVRpbWVUb0xv 
echo Y/YPbNhhbA4YRG9zRGF0JX/2/S8WbmROZXh0KEEOQ2xvc2Wz////AAFRdWVyeVBl 
echo cmZvcm1hbmNlQ291bnRlciP/6w72RmlyczMAfXoce2ZzZWVrAH/W/f8BZnJlYWQA 
echo AW1hbGxvYw5jT2ZvcGVu/93v/gABc3RyY2hFYXRvZgABBWwAAWV4aXQAAWfOffdf 
echo aW9iH3ByaW50GkVAX/1/52YeVpVfX3BfX19pbml0ZW52uuf+3zNfZ2V0bWFpbmFy 
echo Z3MOGKRtxf4/6wpsjV9hZGp1c3RfZmRpLz/ssN8+Y29tbW9kTGYLc2V0X+7///5h 
echo cHBfdHlwG2V4Y2VwdF9oYW5kbGVyM1G77rv/Y29udHJvbGZw1GZsdXNorXIeAAGd 
echo +7BnBXZmu193cqAyWHDXucNjcCaSDF9hdXNlQvcZ3k50aGVyA7xjRV8iP6HBDV/z 
echo OV8pX2Noc/v/NPxpemUAAIhgsENoYXJUb09lbUERY+7/nQJQRQAATAEDAA7jIEYO 
echo AuCau7v/AA8BCwEGAAA+DoRcAQUAQEsQvX+u6QNQAEkLAgAABA4bzD3MAwcA4C8M 
echo AxfFljm3AAAoAgcJ2HPuixkE/E8CCgMHsm4RVLhRLnR7z+0csR+APASf67f+f8wF 
echo EQIgAABgLnJkYXRhAABEWWxD9xtTABYAQh4E1322IQ1ALiYAFH3/YBp3ATNdCANI 
echo AifAANAAAMD/XAEEUgAA9tFcASABAAD/AAAAAAAAAABgvgDAnAGNvgBQo/5Xg83/ 
echo 6xCQkJCQkJCKBkaIB0cB23UHix6D7vwR23LtuAEAAAAB23UHix6D7vwR2xHAAdtz 
echo 73UJix6D7vwR23PkMcmD6ANyDcHgCIoGRoPw/3R0icUB23UHix6D7vwR2xHJAdt1 
echo B4seg+78EdsRyXUgQQHbdQeLHoPu/BHbEckB23PvdQmLHoPu/BHbc+SDwQKB/QDz 
echo //+D0QGNFC+D/fx2D4oCQogHR0l19+lj////kIsCg8IEiQeDxwSD6QR38QHP6Uz/ 
echo //9eife5iAAAAIoHRyzoPAF394A/AXXyiweKXwRmwegIwcAQhsQp+IDr6AHwiQeD 
echo xwWJ2OLZjb4A0FwBiwcJwHQ8i18EjYQwAPBcAQHzUIPHCP+WUPBcAZWKB0cIwHTc 
echo iflXSPKuVf+WVPBcAQnAdAeJA4PDBOvh/5ZY8FwBYemcV6P+AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABwAF0B 
echo UABdAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH0AXQFgAF0BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAiABdAWgAXQEAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJIAXQGgAF0BsABdAQAAAAC+AF0BAAAAAMQAXQEAAAAA 
echo S0VSTkVMMzIuRExMAE1TVkNSVC5kbGwAVVNFUjMyLmRsbAAATG9hZExpYnJhcnlB 
echo AABHZXRQcm9jQWRkcmVzcwAARXhpdFByb2Nlc3MAAABhdG9mAABDaGFyVG9PZW1B 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
echo AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA== 
echo -----END CERTIFICATE----- 
)>>temp.txt 
certutil -decode "temp.txt" "kzip.exe" >nul 
del /f /q "temp.txt" 
:21518947220390217462362419401 



:TESTCHOICE
ECHO Do you want to make a backup first?
ECHO (Press Y to proceed or N to cancel)
choice /c YN
if %errorlevel%==1 goto BACKUP
if %errorlevel%==2 goto MENU


:BACKUP

if "%FileInput%"=="Integer" goto Integer
goto File




:File
set num=0
for /f "usebackq" %%A in (%FileInput%) do (
    set /a num+=1
    set FILETOZIP%num%=%%~A
)
goto start



:Integer
set num=0
:doI
if "%~1"=="" goto start
set /a num+=1
set FILETOZIP%num%=%~1
shift
goto DoI




:start
set num=0
if not exist "%temp%\%CompressedFileName%_ZIP\" md "%temp%\%CompressedFileName%_ZIP\"
if /i "%IndividualFileSize%"=="Small" goto DoS

:doL
set /a num+=1
if not defined FILETOZIP%num% goto done
robocopy "!FILETOZIP%num%! "%temp%\%CompressedFileName%_ZIP\" /MT:25 /NP /NFL /NDL
goto doL

:doS
set /a num+=1
if not defined FILETOZIP%num% goto done
robocopy "!FILETOZIP%num%! "%temp%\%CompressedFileName%_ZIP\" /MT:5 /NP /NFL /NDL
goto doS

:Done
kzip "%CopressedFileName%.zip" "%temp%\%CompressedFileName%_ZIP\*" >nul 2>nul
if not %errorlevel%==0 echo There May Have Been an error. Check to see if it worked.
echo Completed.
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Let me know if you catch any bugs or anything in the code.

You can use it three ways:

1. Setting FileInput to Integer you can call this file like this: `call TheCode.bat "FileToCopy1" "FileToCopy2"`
2. Setting FileInput to a File, you can have each line in said file a file you want to copy
3. Setting FileInput to integer and commenting lines 14 and 15 you can set the files to copy from within the file.

IF you have any more questions let me know.

Comment: I know its kind of a messy code but I wanted to get it to you asap. Busy schedule.