# What is the meaning of -a option in tar.exe command?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, zip, tar

Purpose: zip a folder in window and extract it in linux.

I prefer to https://superuser.com/a/898508/1451256 and I realize there is no description for -a option in tar.exe --help: https://ss64.com/nt/tar.html , so I just follow as the tar official: "tar -cvzf xxx" but when I've tried to extract that zip file in linux by "unzip xxx", it throws error "  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
"

So I suspect the zip file is not zipped properly, then I try to add -a option, it works perfectly. As comment from https://superuser.com/a/1473257/1451256 : it says without the -a option "it assumes a plain tar archive", I don't know what it means. Can someone explains what is the -a option? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[tar(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

```
...
-a, --auto-compress
             (c mode only) Use the archive suffix to decide a set of the
             format and the compressions.  As a simple example,
                   tar -a -cf archive.tgz source.c source.h
             creates a new archive with restricted pax format and gzip
             compression,
                   tar -a -cf archive.tar.bz2.uu source.c source.h
             creates a new archive with restricted pax format and bzip2
             compression and uuencode compression,
                   tar -a -cf archive.zip source.c source.h
             creates a new archive with zip format,
                   tar -a -jcf archive.tgz source.c source.h
             ignores the "-j" option, and creates a new archive with
             restricted pax format and gzip compression,
                   tar -a -jcf archive.xxx source.c source.h
             if it is unknown suffix or no suffix, creates a new archive with
             restricted pax format and bzip2 compression.
...
```

Comment: Teach the boy to fish Tom! :-) "help" is a built-in command of the Bash Shell, documenting commands for that shell. "man" manual pages are the system-wide doumentation system, traditionally of Unix. "info" is yet another, originating from the GNU project... all 3 overlap, but generally "man" is the most readily accessible/comprehensive. So next time, just use "man tar", and here's the online equivalent of that command... www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/

Comment: @user1138 Well, I linked `tar(1)` to the page on man7.org...and yeah if he's on cygwin / msys2 he can probably get man-db or so as well to use `man`.

Comment: All good "man"! (boom-tish) I'll see myself out now...

Comment: thanks all for the information, Sorry but I still don't get it, the link tar(1) belongs to linux, right? What I use is tar.exe, are they the same? What is the different of the zip file when using -a option and not using it?

Comment: Well I have no idea where/how you get it but most likely it's GNU tar anyway (the other popular variant being bsdtar in libarchive). Use `--version` to find out if you want to.

Comment: Note that extension name is always just a *hint*. It does not necessarily reflect what the type the file really is of. If you don't instruct tar to create a zip file with a switch (e.g. -a), it will create a (uncompressed) tarball no matter what you name it (.txt, .exe, .jpg, all the same).

Comment: Btw you do realize there could be different builds for the same software (source) for different platforms/OSes, do you?

Comment: yep, it is: bsdtar 3.3.2 - libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.5.f-ipp,
the tar command I also reference from: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409.
Thanks for the explanation, I have better understanding now.
Regarding different builds for same software: I don't get what you mean? Do you mean different OS like window/linux have different way to kind of read/extract/compress the file?

Comment: No, I mean generally speaking the same piece of code can often be compiled on/for different OSes, e.g. Windows *and* Linux, so `the link tar(1) belongs to linux, right` is not necessarily a thing.

Comment: Ya, something like cross framework, is it? So it will work on both linux and window huh?

Another question related with my understanding, please correct me
1/ if I use tar to zip in windows without -a
- unzip with tar in windows: success
- unzip with 7 zip in windows: fail
- unzip with tar in linux: success
- unzip with unzip in linux: fail
Is it?
2/ so for every soft that from gnu, to check the usages we should use "man xxx"?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example both GNU tar and libarchive are written in C. (But there are platform-specific code/hack in them.) Whether you can use a specific program to *extract* from a zip file depends on whether it support the zip format, and if that's the case, whether it is *really* a zip file (and if it is not, but a tarball, whether the program supports extracting from a tarball). It really isn't relevant the the OS. (And again, it simply will NOT be a zip file unless you tell `tar` with e.g. `-a` to create a zip file.)

Comment: `man` is pretty much the standard way to read a manual (or "man page") of a program in Linux (and most other UNIX-like systems). If you are using cygwin / msys2 in Windows, you can probably rely on that as well. (But AFAIK Windows itself has not shipped the `man` program.) Also, the GNU project sort of endorse/prefer another form of manual, which is their own GNU info. (But their programs have man pages as well, just sometimes simplified.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input